# Cannot remove padding in the button

Tags: xcode, storyboard, stackview

I just want to fit leading Label and button but button has padding from the start.
How can I fit leading?

In this situation three buttons in stackview, label and buttons in stackview.

[image]

Comment: By default, Button text is **centered horizontally** ... it can help to give the elements different background colors so you can see the layout. It also helps to use **real** strings so you can see what happens to the framing. Do you want one of these layouts? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2fP7.png